# DataPicker dialog window not showing properly in some emulator

Tags: android, datepicker

In my application I am using Date picker dialog.During testing some emulator show date picker dialog properly but some emulator show the data picker dialog in properly.Can you explain whether this is a emulator problem or functionality problem as well as how to solve this problem.Thanks...

```
new DatePickerDialog(getSherlockActivity(), datePicker,
           calendarTaskDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
           calendarTaskDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
           calendarTaskDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Here i enclosed the screen shot for both.

Emulator Name:
5.1" WVGA(480x800:mdpi),API level:17

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Emulator Name:Nexus S(4.0",480x800:hdpi) API 12

Comment: What do you mean by "not properly". In API 17 the date picker layout is not the same as in API 12. But I don't see in your pictures what you mean by not "properly". Both images look ok to me ?!?

Comment: From what I know, this is the expected behaviour of `DatePickerDialog`. The first picture shows in old style (GingerBread and before, API<=10). The second picture shows the newer in Holo style, specifically for tablet (HoneyComb, API 11-13)

Comment: @HpTerm Inproper means the date is not view properly in API level 12.See the second image.But it show me fine in API 8 and 10.Why this problem occur in some emulator...

Comment: @AndrewT. So how to solve this problem.Can i add some theme for datepicker.

Comment: Must be my eyes that have problems ;-) in both pictures I see 26th November 2013. If you talk of the layout see my answer below and the one of @GrlsHu.

Comment: Oh sorry, I get the point. You mean that on the left of the last picture you see only the 26 and not november and 2013. This is surely due to the small device width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's default `DatePickerDialog's` layout will be changed according to the API's based on its themes. For the different API's there is a different layout so if you have API below 8 it will be same as your first screenshot. As you go for higher API above 13 you will always get the different layout for your `DatePickerDialog`.

So Its not on our hand to maintain the same layout for DatePicker.

Comment: +1 for specifying that the reference API for different layout is API 13

Comment: I understand your answer but the calendar not showing properly,the dates are hide on the screen so how to solve this.

Comment: It may be because of the lower width of the device and the dialog may not be getting the enough space. There is no way for it.

Answer (score 0):

To me both images look ok.

If what you think is the problem is that the `display` is not the same it is simply due to the fact that in one emulator you use `API 17` and in the other one `API 12`.
In those two API the look of the date picker is not the same.